# MOVE opcode and C APIs in RPGLE

Tags: api, ibm-midrange, opcode, rpgle

**Not** considering code readability, performance and operating system version,
what's the difference between `MOVE` opcode and a C API such as `ATOI`?
How does `MOVE` internally works?

Example:

```
MOVE      ALPHAFLD  NUMRCFLD
EVAL      NUMRCFLD = ATOI(ALPHAFLD)
```

In old O.S. (< V3R7) when should I use `MOVE` and when should I use C APIs?

Comment: In old OS (< V3R7), use MOVE when coding in RPG III and use atoi() when coding in C. Trying to use C APIs in anything but C in V3R6 or V3R1&2 is asking for trouble without good experience. (Experience seems questionable if asking this question.) Finding help for coding so old might be difficult. If using RPG IV nowadays, then normally just redefine the char field as zoned-decimal, though MOVE is available (just should be avoided for good style), and atoi() is fairly easily done. Other possibilities are good today.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your opinion. Actually I also coded in C and C++. My problem arise, as you said, when trying to find good references for old OS. I asked this question because I was curious to know if internally MOVE uses some C APIs

Comment: Can't think why it would. I'd expect it simply to use the [Copy Bytes Right-Adjusted (CPYBRA)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzatk/CPYBRA.htm) MI instruction. Link is to i 7.3, but the instruction has been around from about the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

atoi() and atof() have "always" been available. But RPG programmers have been able to use %INT/%INTH or %DEC/%DECH to convert strings to numerics since V5R2, around the year 2002. %DECH and %INTH do rounding.

MOVE sometimes handles numerics in a bizarre way. For example, let's say you have a variable with 5 digits and 1 decimal position with a current value of 9876.5. Now you MOVE the value '123' to that variable. Try this code to see what bizarre result is in variable "num". Hint: It's not 123.

```
 D num             s              5p 1 inz(9876.5) 
 D msg             s             20                
 C                   move      '123'         num   
 C                   eval      msg = %char(num)    
 C     msg           dsply                         
 C                   return
```

Comment: Tried, 9812.3 - MOVE just move bytes, got it.
Thanks Barbara!

Answer (score 2):

The question may be off topic as it's probably opinion based...

But I'll give you my answer.

First off, `atoi()` isn't the same as `MOVE`.  You'd also need `atol()` and `atof()` to handle all the situations `MOVE` can.  `atof()` is particularily important given the amount of decimal numbers and AS/400 deals with.  But `atof()` isn't really a great choice due to the imprecision of floating point vs. fixed decimal.

But `MOVE` isn't all that great either.  It can't for instance handle negative numbers.

If you're really stuck on an older version of OS/400.  I'd suggest IBM RPG IV compiler developer Barbara Morris' routine... taken from [the Midrange Wiki](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Character_to_number)

```
     H NOMAIN

      * Copy prototype for procedure getNum
     D/COPY GETNUM_PR

      *-------------------------------------------------------
      * getNum - see GETNUM_PR for details
      *-------------------------------------------------------
     p getNum          b                   export
     D getNum          pi            30p 9
     D  string                      100a   const varying
     D  decCommaParm                  2a   const options(*nopass)
     D  curSymParm                    1a   const options(*nopass)

      * defaults for optional parameters
     D decComma        s              2a   inz('.,')
     D cursym          s              1a   inz(' ')

     D result          s             30s 9 inz(0)

     D sign            s              1a   inz('+')
     D i               s             10i 0
     D len             s             10i 0
     D c               s              1a

      * override defaults if optional parameters were passed
     C                   if        %parms > 1
     C                   eval      decComma = decCommaParm
     C                   endif

     C                   if        %parms > 2
     C                   eval      cursym = cursymParm
     C                   endif

      * call getNumAny to do the work
     C                   callp     getNumAny (string
     C                                      : %addr(result)
     C                                      : %len(result)
     C                                      : %decpos(result)
     C                                      : decComma
     C                                      : curSym)

     C                   return    result
     p getNum          e

      *-------------------------------------------------------
      * getNumAny
      *-------------------------------------------------------
     p getNumAny       b                   export
     D getNumAny       pi
     D  string                      100a   const varying
     D  result                         *   const
     D  digits                       10i 0 const
     D  decimals                     10i 0 const
     D  decComma                      2a   const options(*nopass)
     D  currency                      1a   const options(*nopass)

      * defaults for optional parameters
     D decPoint        s              1a   inz('.')
     D comma           s              1a   inz(',')
     D cursym          s              1a   inz(' ')
      * structure for building result
     D resChars        s             30a   based(result)
      * variables for gathering digit information
      * pNumPart points to the area currently being gathered
      * (the integer part or the decimal part)
     D pNumPart        s               *
     D numPart         s             30a   varying based(pNumPart)
     D intPart         s             30a   varying inz('')
     D decPart         s             30a   varying inz('')
      * other variables
     D intStart        s             10i 0
     D decStart        s             10i 0
     D signByte        s              1a   based(pSignByte)
     D sign            s              1a   inz('+')
     D i               s             10i 0
     D len             s             10i 0
     D c               s              1a

      * override defaults if optional parameters were passed
     C                   if        %parms > 4
     C                   eval      decPoint = %subst(decComma : 1 : 1)
     C                   eval      comma    = %subst(decComma : 2 :1)
     C                   endif

     C                   if        %parms > 5
     C                   eval      cursym = currency
     C                   endif

      * initialization
     C                   eval      len = %len(string)
      * begin reading the integer part
     C                   eval      pNumPart = %addr(intPart)

      * loop through characters
     C                   do        len           i
     C                   eval      c = %subst(string : i : 1)

     C                   select
      * ignore blanks, digit separator, currency symbol
     C                   when      c = comma or c = *blank or c = cursym
     C                   iter
      * decimal point: switch to reading the decimal part
     C                   when      c = decPoint
     C                   eval      pNumPart = %addr(decPart)
     C                   iter
      * sign: remember the most recent sign
     C                   when      c = '+' or c = '-'
     C                   eval      sign = c
     C                   iter
      * more signs: cr, CR, () are all negative signs
     C                   when      c = 'C' or c = 'R' or
     C                             c = 'c' or c = 'r' or
     C                             c = '(' or c = ')'
     C                   eval      sign = '-'
     C                   iter
      * a digit: add it to the current build area
     C                   other
     C                   eval      numPart = numPart + c

     C                   endsl
     C                   enddo

      * make sure that there is no overflow
     C                   if        %len(decPart) > decimals
     C                             or %len(decPart) + %len(intPart) > digits
      * Force an overflow exception
     C                   z-add     *hival        overflowSrc       5 0
     C                   z-add     0             overflowTgt       4 0
     C                   eval      overflowTgt = overflowSrc
     C                   endif

      * initialize the result to all zeros
     C                   eval      %subst(resChars : 1 : digits) = *zeros
      * copy the digit strings into the correct positions in the
      * zoned variable, using the character overlay
     C                   eval      decStart = digits - decimals + 1
     C                   eval      intStart = decStart - %len(intPart)
     C                   eval      %subst(resChars
     C                                  : intStart
     C                                  : %len(intPart))
     C                               = intPart
     C                   eval      %subst(resChars
     C                                  : decStart
     C                                  : %len(decPart))
     C                               = decPart

      * if the sign is negative, make the result negative
     C                   if        sign = '-'

     C                   eval      pSignByte = %addr(resChars) + digits - 1
      * Change the sign zone from x'f' to x'd' (b'1111' to b'1101')
      * using a mask of x'2' (b'0010')
     C                   bitoff    X'20'         signByte

     C                   endif

     p getNumAny       e
-----------------------------------------------------------
      * Prototype file
     D getNum          pr            30p 9
     D  string                      100a   const varying
     D  decComma                      2a   const options(*nopass)
     D  currency                      1a   const options(*nopass)

     D getNumAny       pr
     D  string                      100a   const varying
     D  result                         *   const
     D  digits                       10i 0 const
     D  decimals                     10i 0 const
     D  decComma                      2a   const options(*nopass)
     D  currency                      1a   const options(*nopass)  


      *---------------------------------------------------------    
      * getNum - procedure to read a number from a string           
      *          and return a 30p 9 value                           
      * Parameters:                                                 
      *   I:      string   - character value of number              
      *   I:(opt) decComma - decimal point and digit separator      
      *   I:(opt) currency - currency symbol for monetary amounts   
      * Returns:  packed(30,9)                                      
      *                                                             
      * Parameter details:                                          
      *   string:   the string may have                             
      *             - blanks anywhere                               
      *             - sign anywhere                                 
      *               accepted signs are: + - cr CR ()              
      *               (see examples below)                          
      *             - digit separators anywhere                     
      *             - currency symbol anywhere                      
      *   decComma: if not passed, this defaults to                 
      *                 decimal point   = '.'                       
      *                 digit separator = ','                       
      *   currency: if not passed, defaults to ' '                  
      *                                                             
      * Examples of input and output (x means parm not passed):     
      *                                                            
      *        string         | dec | sep | cursym |   result      
      *        ---------------+-----+-----+--------+------------   
      *          123          | x   | x   | x      |   123         
      *          +123         | x   | x   | x      |   123         
      *          123+         | x   | x   | x      |   123         
      *          -123         | x   | x   | x      |   -123        
      *          123-         | x   | x   | x      |   -123        
      *          (123)        | x   | x   | x      |   -123        
      *          12,3         | ,   | .   | x      |   12.3        
      *          12.3         | x   | x   | x      |   12.3        
      *          1,234,567.3  | x   | x   | x      |   1234567.3   
      *          $1,234,567.3 | .   | ,   | $      |   1234567.3   
      *          $1.234.567,3 | ,   | .   | $      |   1234567.3   
      *          123.45CR     | x   | x   | x      |   -123.45     
      *                                                            
      * Author: Barbara Morris, IBM Toronto Lab                    
      * Date:   March, 2000
```

Barbara also participated in a relevent discussion where the above code was posted in the [comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/znDQu5POIBo/0vVCICoR1SoJ)

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. So MOVE doesn't use anything coded in C for data conversion. It uses something like what you posted.
May I ask you in which O.S. versione ATOI/ATOF etc. have been released?
I found an old 1993 book for the V3R7, but nothing prior to that.

Comment: I didn't say that.  I have no idea what `MOVE` does internally. The code I posted is a better alternative than using `MOVE`.  `atoi()`/`atof()` are part of the C runtime.  AFAIK, they have been part of ILE C from the beginning; which was v3r1.